# "Value added time" meaning in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning

Someone says:

> ... due to *coronavirus outbreak* government has imposed *lockdown* across the country to battle against it.
>   Now we are working from home via internet and having more time to spend with family, so we are kind of having **value added time.**

What is the meaning of **value added time** here?

Does it mean **the time is more productive now?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything to me, but it's probably a jokey reference to Value Added Tax (VAT) which you *could* look up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-added_tax), if you thought it mattered. It's probably not worth bothering though.

Answer (score 1):

"Value added" is used as an adjective in some business contexts to refer to goods which have been taken in, and then had something done to them to make them more valuable, and then sold again in their modified (more valuable) form ("value added goods", "value added tax", etc).

This, I believe, originated mainly from the British/European concept of "Value Added Tax", which does not exist in the U.S., and thus is more common in British English than American English.

This quote appears to be attempting to draw a parallel between this practice for manufactured goods vs. doing the same thing for "time", where what would ordinarily be less valuable work time becomes "value added" by the practice of spending it with family in addition to just working.

This is not a common use of the phrase (it's clearly something somewhat invented by the author just for the purposes of this text).